# SKPhysicsJointLimit EXC_BAD_ACCESS?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsjoint

I'm using Sprite Kit (iOS), but whenever I try to add a `SKPhysicsJointLimit` to the `physicsWorld`, the app crashes with `EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xc0)`. Other joint types work fine, which is what's confusing me. Here's an example of what crashes:

```
var node1 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
node1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
self.addChild(node1)

var node2 = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.blueColor(), size: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
node2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50))
self.addChild(node2)

var joint = SKPhysicsJointLimit()
joint.maxLength = 1000
joint.bodyA = node1.physicsBody
joint.bodyB = node2.physicsBody
self.physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

When I replace `SKPhysicsJointLimit()` with `SKPhysicsJointFixed()` (and remove the line setting `maxLength`) or some other joint type, the code works as expected.

I'm new to Sprite Kit, any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The app is crashing because you're not setting the joint's anchor point properties. From the docs, `anchorA` is

> A connection point on the first body in the scene’s coordinate system.

and `anchorB` is

> A connection point on the second body in the scene’s coordinate system.

Here's an example of how to create a `SKPhysicsJointLimit` object with physics bodies and anchor points as arguments:

```
    let joint = SKPhysicsJointLimit.jointWithBodyA(node1.physicsBody!, bodyB: node2.physicsBody!, anchorA: node1.position, anchorB: node2.position)
    joint.maxLength = 1000
    physicsWorld.addJoint(joint)
```

I'm not sure if you can't set the anchor points directly.